# MvvmLight EventToCommand not working anymore

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, windows-phone-8, mvvm-light

I have encountered a rather strange problem using the GalaSoft - MVVM Light Toolkit in a Windows Phone 8 project.
Suddenly (after merging some stuff) all my EventToCommand calls are not working anymore. They worked before. I already tried to remove the MvvmLight toolkit and reference it again with Nuget, but the result stays the same.

One example:

**MainMenuPage.xaml**

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
       ...
       xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
       xmlns:commands="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.WP8"
       ....>

 <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.DataContext >  
    <Binding Source="{StaticResource MainMenuViewModel}"/>
 </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.DataContext>


 <!-- catch back key press -->
 <i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="BackKeyPress">
        <commands:EventToCommand 
            Command="{Binding BackKeyPressCommand}"
            PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
 </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

**MainMenuViewModel.cs**

```
 // back key press command
 public RelayCommand<object> BackKeyPressCommand { get; set; }

 public MainMenuViewModel()
 {
       BackKeyPressCommand = new RelayCommand<object>(
           BackKeyPress,
           (o) => true
           );

       ...
  }

  private void BackKeyPress(Object o)
  {
        // handle back key press
  }
```

This worked perfectly before, but now the BackKeyPress(Object o) Method never gets called anymore. 
This happens for all EventToComamnd calls.

If I remove the xmlns tags, Resharper suggests to add this:

> xmlns:command="http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvmlight"

Result of that:

> The name "EventToCommand" does not exist in the namespace "http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvmlight"

Anyone encountered a similar problem or has an idea what could have caused this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Windows Phone 8.1**

[Windows 8.1 Behavior SDK: How to use InvokeAction with InputConverter to pass arguments to a Command](http://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2014/01/10/windows-8-1-behavior-sdk-how-to-use-invokeaction-with-inputconverter-to-pass-arguments-to-a-command/)

Microsoft has developed it's own EventToCommand functionality. It's located in Behaviors SDK. Someone on stackoverflow told to get this SDK via Nuget. If you can't find the package in NuGet - get it in `Add reference dialog`.

[image]
(My add reference dialog may differs from original because of `Productivity Power Tools` extension)

Here is example of simple usage:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Persons, Mode=OneWay}" 
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPerson, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DisplayPersonCommand}" />
        </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
    </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: My question is quite old and I don't even remember the solution to this problem, but yes we use Microsofts' EventToCommand functionality at the moment so I guess I can mark your answer as correct.

Answer (score 2):

These namespaces are correct.

```
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
xmlns:commands="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.WP8"
```

But your PhoneApplicationPage has wrong DataContext.

```
DataContext="{Binding Path=MainMenuViewModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
```

MainMenuViewModel is property in the ViewModelLocator:

```
public MainMenuViewModel MainMenuViewModel
{
    get
    {
        return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MainMenuViewModel>();
    }
}
```

Btw the argument of BackKeyPress is CancelEventArgs. You should use:

```
public RelayCommand<CancelEventArgs> BackKeyPressCommand { get; private set; }

this.BackKeyPressCommand = new RelayCommand<CancelEventArgs>(this.BackKeyPress)

private void BackKeyPress(CancelEventArgs e)
{
}
```